# Parsing json list when there is an exceptional objects as well using Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, list, gson, retrofit2

Previously I was receiving the response like this:

[image]

I was parsing it like: `Call<List<MyObject>> getList();`

But now there are some new elements were added and the response changed to:

[image]

How to parse this object now? I searched my could not find any solutions.

This is how I am setting up my client.

[image]

This is the json object which i recieve as a response:

`{"map":{"01":{"F":".","E":".","D":null,"C":null,"B":".","A":"."},"02":{"F":".","E":".","D":null,"C":null,"B":"Z","A":"."},"03":{"F":"A","E":"A","D":null,"C":null,"B":"A","A":"A"},"board":false,"type":{"num":"TT334","board":"WW","date":"31MAR","route":"AWETSW","pcount":""}}}`

I dont

Comment: How about sharing your response as **`TEXT`**

Comment: I am sorry @NileshRathod the response is too long. That's why i created this sample. Basically I receive at least 50+ objects. Our API logic changed now I am reciveicing one additional `type` object.

Comment: What json parsing library are you using?

Comment: @Ge3ng edited my question.

Comment: Please share the json and dto object.

Comment: @Ge3ng the question. Added json. Please note that I did not create dto object because I was being able to parse using `Call<List<MyObject>> getList()`.

Comment: Since response is not uniform you should simply use Gson like this Call<JsonObject> getList();

And write all your logic in parser

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential solutions:

1. You create a DTO.  Gson will ignore fields you don't map in your dto. Your json doesn't use a list it is entirely objects.
2. You manually parse the json using Gson's [JsonReader](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)

You can use a mixture of DTOs and manual parsing. I have done this for large json datasets and inconsistent datasets.

Comment: thank you for your respone. I have also considerd this. But unfortunately there some chances that after 1-2 years the size of the objects might increase. Do you really think that this is a viable solution? Is not there another way to handle this? I am little sad honestly.